# Action script events

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events

i am a beginner in action script and i meet some problems with events.

I try de do a quite similar things with flash games like "FarmVille" :

- i have a bar with menu in a "Hbox"
- i have a view in a "Canvas"

When my mouse is inside the Hbox my Canvas still receive mouse events and it makes me unhappy!

I thought to listen for event MOUSE_OVER/MOUSE_DOWN in the HBOX then removelistener/addlistener for mouse events in the Canvas ...

BUT, removelistener needs a "listener" methods and my canvas has, but in another classes ...

I imagine, this is a very common problem and i think it exists a simple, nice way to make this kind of trick ...

Maybe can i also stop the event propagation in the events handler of my HBOX ...
Don't know how to do ...

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `mouseEnabled="false"` on the Canvas element. [More Info](http://www.visualgratis.com/2008/09/05/disabling-mouse-events-in-as3/)